# Adjust column width by default in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I often have to open MS Excel files with columns that are too wide to be displayed within the available space. The result is that the contents is replaced with `#######` and I always have to choose the "adjust column width" option to see what they contain.

Is it possible to tell Excel to use "adjust column width" by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest "auto"-adjust I know: *(works the same in LibreOffice)*

- Click once on the RED square. *("Selects" the entire sheet)*
- Double click on any of the borders indicated by the GREEN dot.

If you have "Format Cell (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>) > Alignment > Wrap" selected for any cell or column, then that can be adjusted too; just pull out the width larger than the length of any text in that column (cell).
*If you do it as second step, after selecting all; it will wide'n all the columns.*

[image]